# Geting error in post and category

Tags: posts, categories, taxonomy

Hallo,

I have in my blog now add a Plugin [Custom Post Type UI] and have great a Post type movies and taxonomies like genre,actors,directer..... like this all ok now i have great a test post min add Movie and add info now come my big problem it show noting in post just a error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in 
>    /home/user***/public_html/**********/****/wp-content/themes/telegraph/functions/wpzoom-functions.php on line 783

Lines 780-786

```
} elseif ( is_single() ) {
  $cat = get_the_category(); 
  $cat = $cat[0];
  echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
  echo $currentBefore;
//      the_title();
  echo $currentAfter;
```

can some on help me by this problem.

PS: do i have to add any code to my theme wen i great a Post type or Taxonomies in [Custom Post Type UI]

Answer (score 1):

```
$cat = $cat[0]->cat_ID;
```

of course if $cat is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Essentially somewhere in that code one of function fails to do what it should and informs about that by returning object of [`WP_Error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) class.

You can use [`is_wp_error()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error) to check for such returns and methods of `WP_Error` class to retrieve errors (and then echo them or something).